# Run Multiple Commands In Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-registry

I want to run the booksServer first, then the customersServer, then fire main.js

But before firing off main.js I want to make sure that customersServer and booksServer are running first.

How do I do this properly?

**Here's my dockerfile now**

```
FROM node:12.14.0
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install nodemon -g
EXPOSE 4555
CMD nodemon /books/booksServer.js && nodemon /customers/customersServer.js && node /main/main.js
```

I know usually you want to separate containers for multiple processes, but I was having gRPC issues when doing this... So I want to try it as a single dockerfile for now.

Comment: I think you'll be better off running 3 containers and instead try to fix gRPC/network issues. `docker-compose` works great for running multiple containers in local development.

Comment: Agreed, I've decided to do that. I'm currently trying to use wait-for-it (https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh) so that the main service waits for the servers to spin up. A bit confused with wait-for-it but looking through some articles

Comment: What about as a workaround, sleep between the commands? `nodemon a.js & sleep 10 && node.....`

Comment: I guess my question was is this a valid CMD?
CMD nodemon /books/booksServer.js && nodemon /customers/customersServer.js && node /main/main.js

Comment: It looks valid according to [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `booksServer.js` and `customersServer.js` are offering ports for communication you could use [this](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) script. The script is commonly used to wait for another service to be ready to used.